# Hbase Spark Connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, connector, bigdata

I am trying to replicate Hbase-Spark connector from https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector. But am badly stuck at

```
rdd.toHBaseTable("mytable")
    .toColumns("column1", "column2")
    .inColumnFamily("mycf")
    .save()
```

After running this line, the error is this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at it.nerdammer.spark.hbase.HBaseSparkConf.createHadoopBaseConfig(HBaseSparkConf.scala:11)
    at it.nerdammer.spark.hbase.HBaseWriter.save(HBaseWriterBuilder.scala:57)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:56)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:58)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:60)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:62)
    at <init>(<console>:64)
    at .<init>(<console>:68)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Also, what value is to be put instead of "the host" in

```
sparkConf.set("spark.hbase.host", "thehost")
```

Any quick help in getting this work would be highly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to resolve this ? pls see my updated answer as well.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for Reply. Will begin to do it now.

Comment: were you able to fix?

Comment: Sorry. I have to get back to this in a few days. But I observed Cloudera in your answer and we are using Hortonworks sandbox. I am not sure if same applies to both these sandbox. I will work on it a few days and will get back to you with updates. Thanks a lot your answers.

Comment: this `driver-java-options -Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=` is common not CDH or HDP related

Comment: if you are okay with answer pls vote-up/"accept-as-owner"

Answer (score 0):

`spark.hbase.host` is ip number of the system where HBase is running.

And for the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration` error, you need to check whether you have HBase dependency jar in your project, if you are running as a jar, you need to check whether your jar contains the below dependency jar.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.94.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

Since you are using Spark Hbase connector, please check below dependency is available in the jar or not.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.nerdammer.bigdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hbase-connector_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, this would have been required when I would have used maven style version as they have mentioned in the documentation of the connector. I cloned the repo and did sbt package which was built successfully. I still don't get where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Indication of Classpath issue.

look at the example submission
https://github.com/cloudera-labs/SparkOnHBase/blob/cdh5-0.0.2/README.md#scan-that-works-on-kerberos

in which you can see

> spark-submit --jars
>   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.3.1.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-protocol.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop2-compat.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core.jar
>   --class com.cloudera.spark.hbase.example.HBaseBulkPutExample --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 512M --num-executors 4
>   **--driver-java-options -Dspark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/***
>   SparkHBase.jar t1 c

```
echo $HBASE_CLASSPATH
```

OR 
`hbase classpath`
if it displays information that need to be added in classpath

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_CLASSPATH
```

otherwise use below manually pointing those.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/*:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.6-cdh5.3.0.jar:/etc/hbase/conf
```